# If a Bank Employer directs me to have my salary paid only into one of their accounts, is that Third Line Forcing?

Tags: antitrust-law, competition

I joined a new job at a Bank, and when filling out the forms, one of the policy documents stated that I had to open an account with them and have my pay paid into that.

I told this to a friend when a legal background, and they said:

> They can't do that, that's Third line forcing.

By [Third Line Forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_line_forcing), she meant an anti-competitive practice where the supply of goods and services is conditional on the purchase of good from a third party.

Australian Law calls this [Exclusive Dealing](https://www.accc.gov.au/business/anti-competitive-behaviour/exclusive-dealing). Acts of this nature are [prohibited](http://www.australiancompetitionlaw.org/law/ed.html) under s47 of the [Competition and Consumer Act](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/cth/consol_act/caca2010265/) 2010.

(I can't find a reference for the equivalent UK or US statutes).

My question is: **If a Bank Employer directs me to have my salary paid only into one of their accounts, is that Third Line Forcing?**

Comment: Employer offers cheaper/free service to employees, to avoid potential conflict of interests. There's nothing wrong with this from an ethical or moral standpoint, I don't see that it would be legally problematic in itself, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, s47 of the Act applies only to the supply of goods and services - that is, where you purchase something from a business or person.

This means that because you are being required to have your salary paid into an account with that bank *as part of your employment contract*, it's unlikely that this would apply.

My understanding is that banks will generally provide an account free of charge - it is unlikely that damages are recoverable (because there are none).

Comment: Wow - great answer. Do the Common Law principles of anti-competitive law apply in this scenario?

Comment: @hawkeye gnasher addresses this point in their answer - it might, but the proportion of the entire market that works for the bank is so small it's unlikely that it would be found to violate anticompetitive behaviour law.

Answer (score 1):

From conversations with bank employees, the reason is that using a different bank means you might be put under strong pressure by a competitor of your employer, which isn't a good idea.

However, in the cases that I knew of, employees would get considerable better conditions than the general public would.

Anti-competitive: Ask yourself, what percentage of the Australian population would be affected by this?